# asp.net modal with iframe, child page runs form_load code while parent loading

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I have a aspx page call it Scheduler.aspx that has an update panel with a repeater, within the repeater ItemTemplate I have a ModalPopupExtender that has an iFrame to another aspx page call this Update.aspx

in the form_load of the Update.aspx page the code checks for some updates from another system and will alert the user that some updates have happened,

what I'm finding is when the Scheduler.aspx page loads the function in update.aspx is fired so I get a number of alerts but don't want this until I go into Update.aspx within the modal,

The function is in if(!Page.IsPostback) but is there anyway I can tell if the page is loading for real or just the parent page loading,

Scheuler.aspx example markup

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updMon" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptMon" runat="server" OnItemCreated="rptMon_ItemCreated">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                <table style="width:100%;" class='<%# sTableClass(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DSC_ID").ToString()) %>'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <asp:LinkButton style="color:#717171" runat="server" id="LinkButton1" href="#">
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DSC_DELNAME") %></asp:LinkButton>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>...</tr>
                </table>
                <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe1" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlMon1" TargetControlID="LinkButton1" ></cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlMon1" runat="server" CssClass="pnlBackGround" align="center" style = "display:none" >
                            <iframe id="iFrm1" class="iframeStyle" src='<%# "Update.aspx?id=" + Eval("DSC_ID").ToString()  %>' runat="server"></iframe>
                                <div id="divClose" style="position:relative;top:-60px;width:200px;left:450px;">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCloseEdit1" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Close" OnCommand="btnCloseEdit1_Command"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DSC_ID").ToString() %>'  />
                                </div>
                        </asp:Panel>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ContentTemplate>
```

the call to the update check in Update.aspx is like this

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
           if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
         {
             sID = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
             CheckUpdates(sID);
      }
}
```

Comment: You want `iframe`s not to load content until some client-side event in the parent page? Set their `src` to `about:blank` during parent page generation, and then change it real value later on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the src link is set on the iframe it's going to load like it's any other resource. The modal popup is just markup on the page that ends up hidden to the browser, but that doesn't mean it's resources can't go out and load. One way around this may be to set the src attribute using javascript and only when the modal is being opened.

Answer (score 0):

Cheers chaps, so this is how I have done it... might not be the nicest way but only way I could think of getting to the iframe within in the repeater,

```
  <iframe id="iFrm1" class="iframeStyle" src="about:blank" runat="server"></iframe>
```

then in ItemCreated on the repeater I've added...

```
    protected void rptMon_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            LinkButton _link = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton1");
            HtmlControl _frame = (HtmlControl)e.Item.FindControl("iFrm1");
            _link.Attributes.Add("onclick", "FrameSrc('MainContent_rptMon_" + _frame.ClientID + "'," + DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "DSC_ID") + ");return false;");
         }
    }
```

then I have a javascript function

```
    function FrameSrc(frame, id) {
    document.getElementById(frame).src = 'ScheduleUpdate.aspx?id=' + id;
    }
```